# Library for displaying a territory/servicing area on a map

Tags: javascript, .net, maps, asp.net

I manage a website for a client whose area of business covers a section of the Midwest US. I created a "territory map" (not sure if there's a better term for it) as a PNG image several years ago, and as you can see, it's very mediocre.

[image]

Their servicing area is expanding, and I'd like use some kind of JavaScript or .NET library on their site to implement a much better map which meets the following criteria:

1. Interactive instead of being a static image
2. Looks better
3. Is easy to make changes to

I don't care if it needs a data source or if you can configure the shape of the territory with click-and-drag. Either method works. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for is [leafletjs](https://leafletjs.com/) which is an open-source JavaScript library for mobile-friendly interactive maps.

You can add layers of [polygons](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#polygon) (specified as lat/long points) to show your boundaries and [controls](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#control-layers) to show/hide the layers.